# In Angular 4 Jasmin testing I am getting [object ErrorEvent] thrown for unexpected testcases

Tags: angular, jasmine

```
it('password field validity', () => {
  let errors = {};
  const password = component.custom_Form.controls['password'];
  expect(password.valid).toBeFalsy();
  errors = password.errors || {};
  expect(errors['required']).toBeTruthy();
});
```

It is showing in the browser like this

```
Login Component password field validity
[object Error Event] thrown
[object Error Event] thrown
[object Error Event] thrown
```

when I am opening this error on the browser it is not showing as failure

```
   1 spec, 0 failures
```

like this it is showing what I have to do..

this error is not coming to this test case regularly... when I am running 
 test cases again means the error is showing for another test case 
 regularly the error is changing to different test cases

Answer (score 0):

Actually when I am running the test cases without mocks, using the original services this 
  error came.Use the mock services only for testing, don't use the original services.